# How to prevent keychain passwords being seen with iPhone passcode?

Tags: iphone, icloud, security, password, keychain

Via `Settings/Safari/Saved Passwords/` it is possible to view all saved passwords by simply entering the 4 digit passcode on ones iPhone.

Is it possible to still be able to use Keychain passwords and autofill, but prevent access by the 4 digit code (e.g. requiring the full Keychain/iCloud password), so that someone who knows your phone code is not able to access all of your internet passwords in plain text?

EDIT: it is possible to set a different 4 digit code as the "Keychain pin" via turning on `Settings/iCloud/Keychain/Advanced/"Approve with Security Code"`, but the phone 4 digit code is still used for accessing the saved Safari passwords as above... It would be great if there was a way to always require the "Keychain pin" instead.

RELATED: the analogous problem on Mac OS X: [How to prevent Safari saved passwords being seen with Mac password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190325/how-to-prevent-safari-saved-passwords-being-seen-with-mac-password).

Comment: This is an excellent point.  I just submitted feedback to Apple, everyone else reading should as well... Several people know my 4 digit passcode for various reasons, that doesn't mean the need to be able to lookup my bank password, and read it in plain text. http://www.apple.com/feedback/

Comment: Another good reason to use something like 1password or equivalent. I don't save any passwords in the browser.

Comment: @Tyson - [others ought to get an auto-notify] I'm not going to go right through this procedure myself, because I don't want yet another password/code to have to remember… but - `Settings/iCloud/Keychain/Advanced/"Approve with Security Code"` below that is 'Change Security Code' which starts by asking your Apple ID p/w.. I cancelled at that point, but someone might want to investigate further...

Comment: Happy to try this out @Tetsujin but I cannot find where you are seeing this in latest iOS - let me know and I'll experiment

Comment: @Psi - yeah, it's long-gone. No idea what happened to it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I figured it out. The option was removed when Apple introduced the concept of iCloud Keychain (before this was an offline keychain only accessed locally). You can create as many keychains as you like but by default your iCloud Keychain will be the one suggested. The password of other keychains can be modified but not of the iCloud Keychain. That uses your iPhone/mac login creds which imo is terrible security design as anyone can look over your shoulder and see your iPhone pin thus access your password database…

Comment: Yeah, though tbh I only use the pin if I have to, otherwise I’ll use touch or face. Harder to hack;)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use an [alphanumeric passcode](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_create_alphanumeric_passcode_ios).

Answer (score 1):

I hate to reference unreleased software, but quite frankly the solution may be for you to enroll now in the iOS 9 public beta or simply wait for it's official Fall release. iOS 9 (at least in its current state) gives the option to set a custom alphanumeric password in place of the familiar 4-digit pin.

So, if you have hardware with touch ID capability you could use that for your everyday login and reserve a more complex passcode (even the same as your iCloud one, like you mention) for protecting your keychain in case of theft, etc.

Comment: iOS has had the alphanumeric passcode capability since iOS 4. iOS 9 introduced six-digit numeric passcodes.